# Cannot install any kind of spring tool to my eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin

I'm studying spring on two different computers. I had no problems with the first one but the other one shows me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF9IF.png) when i try to add spring ide to eclipse:

```
No repository found at http //dist.springsource.com/release/tools/update/e4.5/
```

I've tried installing Spring IDE to two different versions of eclipse:  `Neon` and `Mars`. I've also tried installing Spring Tool Suite (STS) but none of them has worked so far. I googled the error but whatever I found didn't fix my problem.

Anyone can help?

Comment: there is an IDE Spring Tool Suite (STS). use that..

Comment: actually i'd love to. but now i'm following a spring course from john purcell and i believe it would be beneficial if i have everything the same with john's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update site you're using is the the placeholder for the STS update site and sometimes could present problems with some versions of Eclipse. Try the following:

```
Help > Install New Software... > Add...
```

And place the following Location:

```
http://download.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/nightly/e4.5
```

Comment: Have you tried with an older version of Spring, e.g. http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/nightly/e3.6, maybe it could be a proxy issue, do you have any proxy at your network?

Comment: hmm i'm not sure if there is one. maybe i should try when i'm back at work

Comment: Try also cleaning your eclipse cache folder. Delete it: `eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache`, ok?

Comment: Did you restart Eclipse after deleting the cache folder?

Comment: yes i've tried everything but stil it doesn't work. no matter i try installing spring ide or spring tool suite or whatever. it says "no repository found at http //dist.springsource.com/release/tools...."

Comment: It's really weird, did you try this URL instead: `http://download.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/nightly/e4.5`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go to the Preferences -> install/Update -> Available Update Sites, select the one for STS (or multiple ones if you have more than one), and press "Reload". That should cause the cached data to be refreshed.

If this doesn't help, you could try to remove the update site from that list (in the preferences), restart Eclipse, and add it back to that list.